# Python csv reader for row in reader - what does the throwaway underscore represent in this code?

Tags: python, django, csv

I'm reading data from a csv file. I get that 'row' is the variable that represents the loop I am going through, but what is the "_" that is being thrown away here?

```
for row in csv_reader:
  _, Student.objects.get_or_create(
      first_name=row[0],
      last_name=row[1],
      email=row[2],
      organisation=row[3],
      enrolled=row[4],
      last_booking=row[5],
      credits_total=row[6],
      credits_balance=row[7],
      )
```

For example, this code also works:

```
for row in csv_reader:
  Student.objects.get_or_create(
    first_name=row[0],
    last_name=row[1],
    email=row[2],
    organisation=row[3],
    enrolled=row[4],
    last_booking=row[5],
    credits_total=row[6],
    credits_balance=row[7],
    )
```

So I could also ask, why is the "_," even there in the first place?

I found the idea in another question's answer but the purpose of the underscore was not explained.

**UPDATE NOTE**

So it seems that I made a slight error when copying the original code from another post. The original code was:

```
  for row in csv_reader:
    _, result = Student.objects.get_or_create(...
```

which makes more sense now that I see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61229739/1028679). The code is meant to be unpacking the RESULT of the get_or_create and throwing away one value of the tuple. I mistakenly did not copy the result variable as part of my code.

Comment: `_` has to have been defined earlier in your code-block if that code doesn't produce a syntax-error. It could be defined outside of the loop all together, and could be a "scope"-issue with the variable. For instance, what does `type(_)` return?

Comment: Ok so whoever posted the original code did not include the entire file, so there is no way for me to know what "_" actually was. Darn. So yes it does produce a syntax error. Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it so!

Comment: Yeah, if that's the case, then we cannot know why it's being discarded here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a feeling there may be a slight syntax error here.

`get_or_create()` returns a tuple; the object and a boolean (true if the object has been created).

An underscore is sometimes used for one of the elements in that tuple (the bool for example)

`instance, _ = MyObject.objects.get_or_create()`

So here `_, Student.objects.get_or_create` is actually valid python I just think maybe you're missing the second variable to unpack the returned tuple. If you print the type `print(type(_))`, it'll return `"tuple"` and if you `print(_)` you should see a tuple containing the object and the boolean.

Adding the `,` after _ makes `_` a tuple which is why it's not giving you an error, if you remove the `,` it'll throw an error and if you do `_,instance` it'll throw an error as you'd need the `= Student....` if you're unpacking the whole tuple.

Comment: I think you are correct. I've just tracked down the original code and it seems I had a copy/paste error. Updating the question with a Note.

Answer (score 1):

`_` has to have been defined earlier in your code-block if that code doesn't produce a syntax-error. It could be defined outside of the loop all together, and could be a "scope"-issue with the variable.

To give you a weird example for how it can be used though, we can use it inside of another loop and just "catch" the variable and do nothing with it:

```
d = {1:"A", 2:"B", 3:"C"}
for _, value in d.items():
    print(value)
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
```